# MDX Handling Negative Values

Tags: mdx, pentaho, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, mondrian

Do MDX queries not handle negative values very well? Not performance wise, but will you get strange results?

I have a strange result. In the first column of my fact table, I have some negative values that represent null key values.

I am not creating the MDX query. I'm simply dragging and dropping and the software is creating the MDX.

Edit Part 1:
The software I am using is Pentaho User Console. In order to put it into the user console, I have to set the schema and cubes up using the schema workbench.

The actual data itself is accurate.

Normally when I drill down, I get results back to show what user console is drilling down on. With negative values; however, I do not get any values back. I *think* that MDX treats negative values differently, but I am a beginner with MDX and I'm only basing that on my 10-15 minute Google search.

Sample Data:
dimension id values:

```
business_id, carrier_id, at_id, as_id, device_id, created_date_id, created_for_id, cancel_date_id, completed_date_id
```

Measure: activity_count

Sample values for each column:

```
-1, 100, 29, 1, 300, 4269, 500, 1020, -1, 1134
```

Activity count = 1

Edit Part 2:

I am working on getting the MDX logs.

To keep things simple, I am currently putting 
"business_id" on the rows,
my only measure is "activity_count"
and I'm trying to filter for business_id = -1.

I am inexperienced with MDX, but I imagine the MDX would look something like this:

```
select [measures] on columns
from [cube_name]
where [business_filters].[business_id] = -1
```

Now I'm currently getting an error message because it says

```
Mondrian Error:No function matches signature '<Level> = <Numeric Expression>'
```

But I *THINK* this is what the MDX would look like, sort of. What do you guys think?

Edit Part 3:

Interesting Fact: If I go to the database table, my measure value for business_id = -1 is not null for any row.

If I generate some MDX, the value is Null. If I replace the -1 value with a positive value, the returned measure is accurate. Why is this . . .

```
select
    non empty {[Measures]}
on  columns,
    [business_filters].[business_id].[-1]
on  rows
from
    [activities_fact_01]
```

Comment: What's the software?  Can you provide: sample values, expected output and actual output?

Comment: I edited my post above to answer your questions.

Comment: within excel and pyramid we've not noticed negative numbers being "treated differently" - I don't understand your question though: _when is it being treated differently?_

Comment: I could not figure out for the life of me why the measure said my value was 32, but when I tried to drill down, I got no data returned (this only happens with negative key values). My theory was that MDX does not work well with negative numbers. But I do not know MDX very well, so I could be wrong.

Comment: you need to find out what mdx is being generated when you drill down - it is probably just returning null

Comment: Yup, I'm currently working on doing that. Just out of curiosity, can you tell me what the MDX would look like if I wanted "Business_ID" on rows and the "measure" on the columns? I'm just curious. Even without the MDX Log, I can get an idea as to what might be happening that is wrong. There are no null key values btw, but I'm filtering for business_id = -1.

Comment: I edited my post, please look at part 3 when you have the chance :)

Comment: That's so weird. When I replace all of the negative key values with positive ones, it works fine.

Comment: @LunchBox: According to my experience with Pentaho Analyzer, there should not be any issues with negative IDs, if data and schema are correct. Can you add some excerpts from your schema xml? At least definition of `business_filters` dimension (or shared dimension + dimension usage) and the `<Table>` element under your `<Cube>` element?

Comment: I apologize for the late response; however, I figured out what was wrong. I spent about an hour trying to confirm. The problem was bad (not null or negative) foreign key values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong.

It had to do with having foreign key values that were not in dimensions. When I went to drill down in Pentaho, these results did not come back because the foreign keys did not have corresponding primary key values.

I spent 1.25 days trying to figure this out, but you can bet I'll never make that mistake again :)